# CSS Change background for group of records( NOT Alternate)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table, I need the first 4 records to have the same background color.

**Example:** First 4 records will all have background Yellow.

I need the next 4 records will all have background of Blue.
Therefore the following 4 will be Yellow.

I cannot figure out how to use the `tr:nth-of-type` to group multiple records.

I can get the Alternate however I cannot get the background color for multiple records.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to edit the table elements directly and place <div> tags within each <td> element?  or is your content being dynamically populated into multiple <td> elements?

Comment: what about showing the code you've got?

Answer (score 4):

http://cssdeck.com/labs/i8zohrrs

```
tr:nth-child(8n+1),
tr:nth-child(8n+2),
tr:nth-child(8n+3),
tr:nth-child(8n+4) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

If you're coloring the rows this way because they have some sort of relationship, it might be better to wrap them in a tbody tag:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/KqoCs

```
tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #CCC;
}

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Example that will add background color to the second

tag.
The HTML:====>>>

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

The below code is css:====>>>>

```
p:nth-of-type(2)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As with most things there are a few ways to go about it,

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/pUSAf/2/)**

CSS methods:

```
tr{
    background:green; /* all */
}
.orange{    
    background:orange; /* add class .orange */
}
tr:nth-child(3n+3){
    background: yellow; /* every 3rd child */
}

tr:nth-child(2){
    background: blue; /* 2nd child only*/
}
```

jQuery Method:

```
$('tr').slice(10, 13).css('background-color', 'red');  // select tr 11-13
```